# list index out of range - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I am writing this python code by using pandas to analyze some stock data. I am using two too loops for getting cumulative profit.But it gave me list index out of range error. Anyone could help? df is dataframe I am using and it has about 10 columns included 'invest' and 'percent change'. df['invest'] column is all binary numbers 1 or 0 and df['percent change'] is stock price changed compared with last day. windows here mean if I see windows consecutive 0 such as 2 consecutive 0, I am going to buy this stock and sell it the next day.

This one is my assignment. It is not really stock analysis. So please do not take the analytics method too seriously. These just for demonstrating python for data science

```
count=0
countseq=0
principal=100
windows=[1,2,3,4,5]
profit_loss=[0,0,0,0,0]
for i in windows:
    for j in range(len(df)-1):
        if df['invest'][j]==0:
            count+=1
            if count==i:
                profit_loss[i]+=principal*df['percent change'][j+1]
                count=0 
                countseq+=1


IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-53972da7243a> in <module>()
     10             count+=1
     11             if count==i:
---> 12                 profit_loss[i]+=principal*df['percent change'][j+1]
     13                 count=0
     14                 countseq+=1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: try `for j in range(len(df['percent change'])):`

Comment: no, it did not work.I think it is because of i, but I am not sure @Ruzihm

Comment: You're using the values of `windows`, with max `5`, to index into `profit_loss`, whose max index is `4`. Remember that python is zero-indexed

Comment: In other words, do `for i in range(len(profit_loss)):` and  `for j in range(len(df['percent change'])):`

Comment: it worked! @G.Anderson

Comment: Adding as answer, since it helped solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the values of `windows`, with max `5`, to index into `profit_loss`, whose max index is `4`. Remember that python is zero-indexed